# Swipe left or right to select (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter, so basically what i'm trying to do is that the user can swipe to the left or right to select the item as shown on the image, i've searched about and find nothing. thank you in advance

[image: If user swipe left it will select false alarm, and if right it will select bomba]

Comment: PageView  ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A&vl=en

Comment: see [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) class

Answer (score 0):

See [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) for your implementation.